# sudo apt-get remove unity

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde

Just what sort of problems would doing the above command lead to. I have installed kde desktop and would like a pure kde DE. I understand theres kubuntu but I've done so much with this one now that I'd be loathe to do it all again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would remove the Unity desktop environment itself, so that when you log in, the Unity session option will no longer be available. If you will never use Unity, there should be no problem.

Be aware that there are many dependencies of `unity` that may not automatically be removed. To save disk space, you could also uninstall them. When doing so, remember to check before hitting Enter to make sure that `apt-get` isn't trying to uninstall half your system.

A few Unity-related things you probably should leave: `libunity9` (many GNOME applications depend on this).

Assuming you are already using the KDE login screen (which is separate from the default Ubuntu one), you can also remove `unity-greeter`.

Comment: Yes because currently when I boot up the KDE login screen appears.

Comment: "you probably should leave: libunity9 (many GNOME applications depend on this)."... how could the ubuntu developers possibly think that would be a good idea? Ubuntu is starting to be more and more like windows :(

Comment: I have successfully removed unity. The only other thing I removed was nautilus since I use dolphin. I seem to be all in one piece :D

Comment: @MiJyn: It is odd. I asked http://askubuntu.com/questions/252325/why-do-many-gnome-application-packages-depend-on-libunity9.